# Fallos de impresión de caracteres especiales en c# visual studio 2019

Tags: c#

pasa que estoy usando visual studio 2019 para programar en C#, el problema surge al momento de realizar el siguiente programa:

```
int i = 0, totalV = 0, totalC = 0;
        string frase = "", vocales = "aeiouáéíóúü", letra = "", num = "1234567890";

        Console.Write("Ingrese una frase: ");
        frase = Console.ReadLine(); 

        while (i < frase.Length)
        {
            letra = frase.Substring(i, 1).ToLower();
            if (vocales.Contains(letra))
                totalV++;
            else if (letra != " " && !num.Contains(letra))
                totalC++;

            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("La frase {0} tiene {1} vocales y {2} consonantes", frase, totalV, totalC);
```

El objetivo del programa es mostrar si, ejemplo: si yo ingreso la frase hola el programa me muestra que tiene 2 vocales y 2 consonantes, todo trabaja de maravilla el problema surge cuando ingreso una palabra con carácter especial, ejemplo

Ingrese una frase: aarón
lo que quiero que salga: `la frase aarón tiene 3 vocales y 2 consonantes`

lo que sale: `la frase aarn tiene 2 vocales y 3 consonantes`

Ya revise en **herramientas/configuración/editor de texto/detectar automáticamente codificación UTF-8 sin signatura**

Incluso ya lo actualice y restauré la configuración a la original, pero aún así no funciona, me gustaría una solución que no implique utilizar ascii, muchas gracias

Comment: Una cosa es detectar codificación al abrir, otra es [al guardar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2019#to-save-a-file-with-encoding).

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedas hacer es "remover los acentos", o sea intercambiar los acentos por el caracter sin el mismo.

- Ejemplo: **[é|é|è|ë|ê]** >> **e**

Asi puedes comparar si importar el tipo de codificacion o acentuacion.

Todo esto depende de la funcionalidad que necestias.

Por ejemplo podrías utilizar un [metodo extensor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) de string para "intercambiar" o quitar estos acentos

Una alternativa de ejemplo:

- [StringExtensions > RemoveAccents](https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/54428a9ac58e9e34aea9a5a287dc399f#file-stringextensions-cs)

  ```
   public static class StringExtensions
   {
       public static string RemoveAccents(this string textInput)
       {
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textInput))
           {
               return string.Empty;
           }

           var sb = new StringBuilder();

           var arrayText = textInput.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).ToCharArray();

           foreach (char letter in arrayText)
           {
               if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(letter) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                   sb.Append(letter);
           }
           return sb.ToString();
       }

  }
  ```

En tu ejemplo

```
frase = Console.ReadLine().RemoveAccents();
```

Un ejemplo online con tu codigo que lo puedes ejecutar directamente en el browser

- https://dotnetfiddle.net/acuIC1

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía